# Upper bound for $\sum_{x=1}^l \left(\frac{s}{x}\right)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $l,s$ be some large numbers (if it helps, you might assume $s \gg l \gg 1$) and consider

$$S:=\sum_{x=1}^l \left(\frac{s}{x}\right)^x.$$

What one can easily do is the following:

$$S \leq \sum_{x=1}^l s^x=\frac{s^{l+1}-1}{s-1}-1,$$

but this approximation is too coarse for what I need.

Do you know some non-trivial (or even trivial) upper bounds on this sum?

If not, do you maybe know an upper bound on $$S':=\sum_{x=1}^l \frac{s^x}{x!}$$

Thank you very much for any hint!

Comment: An obvious upper bound is $S' < exp(s)$, and that one is tight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering $$S'=\sum_{x=1}^l \frac{s^x}{x!}$$ the result is simple if you already know about the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $$S'=\sum_{x=1}^l \frac{s^x}{x!}=e^s\frac{ \Gamma (l+1,s)}{\Gamma (l+1)}-1=e^s\frac{ \Gamma (l+1,s)}{l!}-1$$ which tends to $e^s-1$ if $l\to\infty$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for the input. 
Does this also hold if $l \rightarrow \infty$, but $l = o(s)$?
So for example if we let $l=\log(s)$?